# Updating external DBMS tables with SAS data using PROC SQL passthrough -- is this possible?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a MS Access database. I am required to process and update tables in this database with SAS. The tables can be very large. Some of the processing requires the use of pure SAS functions. With a SAS/ACCESS LIBREF to MS Access, you cannot update or alter tables with PROC SQL. Therefore, I see two approaches:

1. Using LIBREF: Copy the entire table into SAS. Delete the original table in Access. Process the table in SAS. Write the table back to Access.
2. Using PROC SQL passthrough: Read the rows I need into SAS. Process these rows using SAS. Update the rows in Access.

My question: is number 2 even possible? With SQL functions (rather than SAS), the process outlined in number 2 is many orders of magnitude faster than number 1. I understand that this difference comes from the data being processed entirely by the DBMS, but number 2 would still have to be faster, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers: I asked this question because SAS does not support a `PROC SQL` `UPDATE` statement on a MS Access library. To update an Access table, you must create a new table in the database and use a pass-through statement. My first instinct was to use an `UPDATE` statement assigning with a `WHERE` clause to update a subset of records. While I was researching this, I read some bad information that said Jet SQL did not support updating a subset of records. This is incorrect. Using an `INNER JOIN`, you are able to update a subset. Example code below:

```
/* Access database is "C:/database.mdb".
   Original table in database is "original". 
   Processed table is "work.updates". */

libname mdbfile "C:/database.mdb";

proc sql;
create table mdbfile.updates as select * from work.updates;
connect to access (path="C:/database.mdb");
execute (
  update original as a inner join updates as b on a.id = b.id
  set a.variable1 = b.variable1
  where condition = 1
) by access;
execute (drop table updates) by access;
disconnect from access;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'd suggest is option 2, then use LIBREF to upload those rows to a temporary table, then use passthrough to update the bigger table.  It may be possible to update the rows directly via libref, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with SAS connection to Access to answer that part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This would be faster, but in trying it I found out that Access doesn't allow CREATE TABLE statements from external programs, so I can't get the updated column on to the original table. Also, it isn't possible to update a table in Access via a LIBREF.

Comment: How are you connecting to the access database?  The code `libname test 'c:\temp\test.accdb';

data test.class;
set sashelp.class;
run;
` works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct LIBNAME statement. You can create a new table using the LIBREF with a DATA step or PROC SQL. You cannot (at least I am pretty sure you cannot) use a CREATE TABLE statement in a PROC SQL pass-through to Access; that is, you cannot use CREATE TABLE inside an EXECUTE ... BY ACCESS statement.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the idea.  Pull down the data you want to process, process, then create a table via LIBREF, then update the main table from the created table via passthrough.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. Maybe this is my limited experience with SQL, but how would you update the table once it is in the Access database? From what I can tell, you can't use a SELECT statement as part of an Access UPDATE statement, so you would have to merge on the new data first, wouldn't you?

Comment: Some of this depends on exactly what you're doing.  Are you updating a single value or a couple of values, or largely replacing whole rows?  What's the UPDATE statement you'd  use if you did it via LIBREF?

Comment: Well, you can't the ACCESS engine I have doesn't support UPDATE statements on Access tables, so you have to use a pass-through. To provide an answer though: `update original_table set var = (select modified_var from modified table) where _condition_=1`. If I could actually use the LIBREF, I would use the SAS function I need rather than the subquery.

Comment: I also recognized that the UPDATE statement I just wrote could be incorrect since the SELECT returns multiple rows.

Comment: That same subquery should work via pass through, with modified_table being the table you create in ACCESS via LIBREF.  You'd just modify the select query to include where _condition_=1.

Comment: I left out the condition in the statement above because I meant for all rows in modified_table to be _condition_=1, but I never said that anywhere. Anyway, I tried that query both with and without the _condition_=1 in the subquery. The error I receive is `ERROR: Operation must use an updateable query.`

Comment: I was wrong about the update statement. See my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When using the LIBNAME statement to connect to an Access database, you need to add the option 'scan_text=no' in order to enable updating that databse.  You can then use MODIFY to change existing records or APPEND to add new records.  Below is some training code I wrote a while ago, this connects to Excel but the principle is the same for Access.

```
/* Create libname to Excel */
libname xl 'N:\SAS\Code\sas_training\sample_data\range.xls' scan_text=no; /* important to use this option */

/* Create table with updated values */
data xl_update;
input month a b c d;
cards;
200909 1 2 3 4
200910 5 6 7 8
200911 10 11 12 13
run;

/* Extract latest month from existing data */
proc sql noprint;
select max(month) into :maxmth
from xl.testdata;
quit;

/* Update existing values */
data xl.testdata;
modify xl.testdata xl_update (where=(month<=&maxmth.));
by month;
run;

/* Append new rows to exisiting data */
proc append base=xl.testdata 
            data=work.xl_update (where=(month>&maxmth.));
run;

libname xl clear;
```